# Schedule specific triggers for every entry in the DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a dynamo db and every entry has a specific cron expression on which we need to perform actions for the entry.

Basically, I want every entry in the dynamo to have a custom cron expression(they can be different for all the entries) on the basis of which a schedule is triggered and the contents of the entry is sent to a queue or published to an SNS topic in the form of a message.

Is that possible to achieve via CloudWatch events? As in, having a specific CloudWatch event for every entry in the DynamoDb?
Also, can it be done in a different way if not CloudWatch?

Comment: Hi, it will be much easier to answer your question if you can provide a few more details. Can you tell us what, if anything, you have already tried? Also, you may want to take a look at this overview of how to set up distributed job scheduling in AWS. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/distributed-job-scheduling-for-aws/

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamodb streams to trigger a step function on insert event